# Convert java object in to pipe delimited string

Tags: java, string, serialization

Suppose there is class:

```
public class Employee 
{
   private String name;
   private String age;
   private String birthdate;
   private String location;
}
```

We have an object with values name = John, age = 25, birthdate = September 10, location = houston. Is there an easy way or an efficient way to convert that object into a pipe delimited string as shown below?

```
John|25|September 10|houston
```

I could think of only one solution - just appending the values of members of object into a string. I want to know if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: This is what the toString method should be for.

Comment: Note that `age` and `birthdate` really shouldn't be strings.

Comment: I just gave an example. That is not my actual class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String.format

```
System.out.println (String.format ("%s|%s|%s|%S", name, age, birthdate, location));
```

Chuck this into your overriden `toString` method

Comment: This most likely does not belong in the toString method. It very much looks like some interface / communication thing and therefore probably should go into a separate class.